# No Service Mark Symbol in Delphi 6,7

Tags: delphi

I am trying to print SM symbol on report which is using Delphi 6
form to insert symbol on quick report panel.

Alt + 8480 is the symbol in word but when I tried same in Delphi 6
it either change in to box or ?.

When I see ascii character list it contain copyright, trademark etc.
but it does not contain Service Mark symbol and I can print service
mark symbol in Delphi 10.3 so I believe it is the issue with support of
Unicode.

Anyone have idea how to do this in Delphi 6,7.

Thanks.

Comment: Does quick report support Unicode in Delphi 6/7? Why are you fighting on with a pre Unicode Delphi?

Comment: Thanks for your message, Actually in Delphi 6  forms are created similar like Quick report. I believe they are extended components of  quick report or Simple Delphi form exists in rpt format. When I execute these rpt files in Delphi and whenever I entered ALT + 8480  for the lable it keep there and as I press ok It changed into ? mark but it works in Delphi 10.3

Comment: As David just said, old Delphi versions do not support Unicode out of the box...

Comment: Judging by your reply to my comment I wonder if you fully appreciate that Delphi 6/7 don't support Unicode text in their string type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because pre-Delphi 2009 Delphi `string` is not Unicode, but has a `CharSet` (aka CodePage), you won't be able to directly encode this on Delphi 6,7 on most systems. Some asian charsets may be able to display it, but it will work only if the Windows system non-Unicode app charset is set as such.

Of course, you could try to switch to an Unicode version of QuickReport - using `WideString` instead of string. But I doubt there is any for Delphi 6/7. Or switch to a newer version of Delphi. But I doubt it is possible for you.

What you could do easily is:

- just write `'(sm)'` text with the current font;
- or draw it by switching to a smaller font size, manually writing the two small `sm` characters, then switch back to the normal font size - I guess QuickReport may have some event for custom `TCanvas` drawing;
- or try to find a font including the ServiceMark glyph in its main #0-#255 page (but I don't know any).

Comment: Hi Arnaud, Thanks for your replay. I thought the same if unicode does not work I will put either SM Image logo or Smaller font. Just want to make sure that Delphi 6,7 does not support that I feel most of other views are similiar like that.